# React Navigation redirect user based on a context state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have added a state called `roleSelected` the initial value for this `roleSelected` is `false`, which presents in my `AuthContext`

```
const [roleSelected, setRoleSelected] = useState(false);
```

My stack navigation screens are like this,

```
<Stack.Screen name={routes.LOGIN} component={Login} />
<Stack.Screen name={routes.SIGNUP} component={Signup} />
<Stack.Screen name={routes.ROLE_SELECTION} component={Role} />
```

**What I'm trying to do**: So if the `roleSelection` is `false`, no matter which screen I'm currently in this stack I want to redirect the user `ROLE_SELECTION` route. So for this case I added the following code in my `Login` and `Signup` screens,

```
const Login = ({navigation}) => {
  ...
  const {roleSelected} = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    !roleSelected && navigation.navigate(routes.ROLE_SELECTION);
    console.log(roleSelected);
  }, [navigation]);
```

Whenever the app starts user redirects to the `ROLE_SELECTION` route, but still the user can click back and go to the `Login` screen, I don't want that to happen. Really appreciate it if somebody could help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried conditionally rendering the stack screens like this,

```
{!auth && <Stack.Screen name={routes.LOGIN} component={Login} />}
{!auth && <Stack.Screen name={routes.SIGNUP} component={Signup} />}
{auth && <Stack.Screen name={routes.ROLE_SELECTION} component={Role} />}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try instead of `navigation.navigate` to use `navigation.reset` that wipe the navigator state and replace it with a new route.

Comment: Can you explain with my code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding one more useEffect() with an empty dependency array into your code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    !roleSelected && navigation.navigate(routes.ROLE_SELECTION);
    console.log(roleSelected);
  }, []);
```

Comment: I tried this but giving me the same issue